# Enable an external website to resolve to a page on my parent website, keeping URL the same

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, .htaccess

I have a domain, www.example.COM. I have a page on that domain, www.example.com/page. I have another domain, www.example.NET and I want that domain to resolve to the page first mentioned, www.example.com/page

So basically when someone goes to www.example.net it resolves to www.example.com/page but the url remains www.example.net in the address bar.

So far, I can successfully make www.example.net resolve to www.example.com (the home page) through setting the DNS at the registrar. Now that I can do that, is it something with virtual hosts, .htaccess, apache config or something else on my server whereas I can specifically make this domain-b.com resolve to this specific page on domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ServerAlias command, like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain-b.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/my/files

  [ extra web app stuff here ... ]

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Or, if you need slightly different settings for each domain you can have multiple VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/my/files

  [ extra web app stuff here ... ]

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.com-error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain-b.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/my/files

  [ extra web app stuff here ... ]

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain-b.com-error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain-b.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It really depends on your needs beyond just the domain name.

If you are already doing this and it's not working, then perhaps your web app needs to have specific settings to make this work. It's not uncommon for web apps to be specific about the domain that is accessing it and to redirect any unknown domains to the domain in settings. For instance, WordPress is known for doing this.

If changing the web app settings is not an option then you should consider using nGinx as a reverse proxy in-front of Apache and modify the in/out headers and data, but this would be an absolute last resort because it assumes too many things we can't know about your web app and it would be bad for performance.

Furthermore, I would be remiss if I did not warn you that if you intend to make this a public facing web page then this set up could be bad for you Search Engine traffic because it would be considered duplicate content.